# How to configure logback by excluding sub package?

Tags: logback

I have packaging structre like beow

### Packages

```
com.service.main
com.service.validation
com.service.subscriber
com.data.a
com.data.b
com.data.c
```

I want to create 3 appenders
one for all data.*
one for all service.* (except subscriber)
one for all service.subscriber

I cannot use root here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add separate logger for this package and set additivity flag.
[Documentation.](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#cumulative)

More concrete logger will be triggered. Other loggers will ignore this package as you have more specific (and with turned off "additivity").